# Variables accepted by apache in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am using things like:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^.*\.(htm|html|php|txt)$#i">
```

...

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ m#^.*TTT.*$#i">
```

And I would like to know all the variables Apache accepts inside this clause of my .htaccess file. If I am receiveing a custom header like XXX how do I work with it inside the conditional above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For list all the available variables in expressions [check this official Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/expr.html#vars).

To check a custom header use:

```
<If "%{HTTP:My-Custom-Header} =~ /something/">
...
</If>
```